# Flutter How to save a PDF in a folder created by a user

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, directory

I'm trying to allow user to save a PDF on his phone if the user select a default folder it's ok.
Now I would like to allow the download in a folder created by the user. How can I perform this ?

For example: The user clicks on a download button > He clicks on create a folder > New folder > Folder name > MyNewFolder

How can I get the path of this new created folder and donwload in it a PDf instead of an existing folder if the user create this new folder.

**PDFViewModel**

```
class PDFViewModel extends ViewModel<PDFListModel> {

  static final provider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<PDFViewModel, PDFListModel>((ref) {
    return PDFViewModel(
      initialState: const PDFListModel(pdfLIst: []),
      pdfStream: [],
      sessionManager: ref.watch(SessionManager.provider),
    );
  });

  PDFViewModel({required PDFListModel initialState,
    required List<PDFModel> pdfStream, required this.sessionManager}) : super(initialState);

  final SessionManager sessionManager;
  final storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();
  int id = 0;
  late Saf saf;
 
  Future<int> readId() async {
    String? idString = await storage.read(key: "id");
    int? id = int.parse(idString!);

    return id;
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Download PDF
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Future<File?> downloadPdf(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      id = await readId();
      String fileName = "my_PDF_${DateTool(DateTime.now()).toFileDateHour()}.pdf";
      return savePdf(fileName);
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      if(error is HttpException){
        if(error.message.contains("EXPIRED_SESSION")){
          context.showErrorSnackBar(Translation.current.expiredSession);
          Future.delayed(
              const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
            ref.read(SessionManager.provider).logOut();
          }
          );
        }
        else{
          context.showErrorSnackBar(Translation.current.noWebService);
        }
      }
      else{
        context.showErrorSnackBar(Translation.current.noWifi);
      }
      logger.e('PDFViewModel download PDF\n$error', error, stackTrace);
    }
    return null;
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Save PDF
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Future<File> savePdf(String fileName) async {
    final repository;
    if(Platform.isIOS || Platform.isMacOS){
      final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      repository = directory.path;
    }
    else {
      var androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
      var sdkInt = androidInfo.version.sdkInt;

      if(sdkInt == 29){
        repository = Environment.android10Path;
      }
      else {
        repository = Environment.android11Path;
      }

      // Check the permission status --------------------------------
      saf = Saf(repository);
      bool? isGranted = await saf.getDirectoryPermission(isDynamic: true);

      // Ask SAF storage permission if needed -----------------------
      if (isGranted != null && !isGranted) {
        await saf.getDirectoryPermission(isDynamic: true);
      }

      // Android 10 -------------------------------------------------
      var state = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
      var state2 = await Permission.storage.status;
      if (sdkInt == 29 && !state.isGranted) {
        await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
      }
      if (sdkInt == 29 && !state2.isGranted) {
        await Permission.storage.request();
      }
    }

    // Android 11+ --------------------------------------------------
    final file;
      bool dirExists = await Directory(repository).exists();
      if (!dirExists) {
        await Directory(repository).create();
      }
    file = File("$repository/$fileName");
    Uint8List bytes  = await sessionManager.pdfCertificate(id.toString(), fileName);
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return file;
  }

  Future<Uint8List> getCachedPDF() async {
    Uint8List bytes  = await sessionManager.cachePDFCertificate(id.toString());
    return bytes;
  }

}
```

---

**Environment**

```
abstract class Environment {

  Environment._();

  static const android10Path = 'storage/emulated/0/Download';
  static String android11Path = '${Environment.android10Path}/defaultFolder';

}
```

**Edit:** Actually if the user create a folder the PDF will be donwloaded in this folder **and** in the default folder. How can I check if a folder is created to don't dowload it twice.